# Problems fading in and hiding div

Tags: jquery

Im having an issue with some jquery im using. I want to be able to hover a songs album cover which will then display a play button and allow me to play a song. At the moment though when I hover the album cover all the divs containing the same div name for the play button seem to show on the page. How can I icolate the play button to only show on the albumcover I am actively hovering. Also how can I stop the button from fading in and then fading out straight away?

Im using this jquery code at the moment

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{    
 $("#cover_overlay").hover(
  function () {
    $(".el-play").fadeIn('slow');
  },
  function () {
    $(".el-play").fadeOut('slow');
  }
);
});

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: you will have to show us the html. without that this is a guessing game. i would guess you should use this: $(".el-play", this).fadeIn('slow');

Comment: @mblase75 sorry, here you go. the hover doesn't seem to be working in jsfidddle for some reason :S http://jsfiddle.net/jY2hL/

Comment: @Daniel http://jsfiddle.net/jY2hL/

Comment: @DanFarrell Your fiddle has MooTools selected on the left.

Comment: @mblase75 try this one. it also does that flashing thing with the code im using which I need stopping aswell
http://jsfiddle.net/jY2hL/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem in your jsFiddle is that you're assigning the same ID to multiple elements. This is a no-no, as JavaScript will only select the first element it finds with a given ID. You need to replace all those IDs with classes.

Second, you're selecting the `el-play` button with a class, so EVERY element with that class will be faded in and out at the same time.

Third, you have a problem in that moving the cursor over the `.el-play` button counts as moving it off of `.cover_overlay`, so the button immediately fades out. You need to add a handler for the `.el-play` element as well to cover this.

Here's one approach that works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jY2hL/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.onPlay = false;
    $(".cover_overlay").hover(function() {
        $(this).prev(".el-play").fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(!window.onPlay) { 
                $this.prev(".el-play").fadeOut('slow');
            }}, 100);
    });

    $('.el-play').hover(function() {
        window.onPlay = true;
    },function() {
        window.onPlay = false;
    });
});
```

If that doesn't work, please study the [jQuery tree traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to figure out exactly how to get from `.cover_overlay` to `.el-play`.

Answer (score 0):

If `.el-play` is inside `#cover_overlay`, change

```
$(".el-play").fadeIn(); //and fadeOut
```

To

```
$(this).find(".el-play").fadeIn(); //and fadeOut
```

Otherwise, you'll probably have to play with `.closest()` and then `.find()`.

As to fading out - make sure the element you're fading in does not obscure the element that you are hovering over, otherwise you will trigger `mouseout` and thus fade out the element.